# Vertically center a div in grid using Tailwindcss

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid, tailwind-css, tailwind-3

I am trying to centre a div present inside a CSS Grid horizontally and vertically. I am using TailwindCSS v3. Using `mx-auto`, I can align the content horizontally, but `align-middle` along with flexbox isn't showing any results. I am attaching the code snippet below.

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-6 mb-2">
  <div className="col-span-1">
    <div className="flex align-middle">
      <ImLocation className="text-lg text-black mx-auto" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <div className="col-span-5">
    <p className="text-sm md:text-base text-black">
      Address Line 1, <br />
      Address Line 2, <br />
      Address Line 3
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue here is that the first inner-div (with class `col-span-1`) has a smaller height than the other div. I want that div to align in the centre with the other div vertically. ImLocation is a react icon that I have used.

Answer (score 3):

Use `items-center` and `justify-center` like below:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-6 mb-2">
    <div className="col-span-1">
        <div className="flex flex-row items-center justify-center">
            <ImLocation className="text-lg text-black mx-auto" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div className="col-span-5">
        <p className="text-sm md:text-base text-black">
            Address Line 1, <br />
            Address Line 2, <br />
            Address Line 3
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```